# VBA - Insert images in corresponding cell Based On Cell Value and return nothing, if cell is empty or if image is missing

Tags: excel, vba, image

The below code seems off as it doesn't seem to pull images consistently.

1. For empty cells it displays "The linked image cannot be displayed"
2. For some of the non-empty cells, the macro doesn't seem to pulling any image and instead returns the same error as above "The linked image cannot be displayed"

```
Sub Insert_Multiple_Images()

Set Image_Names = Range("D2:D68")
Image_Location = "D:\Image"
Image_Format = ".jpg"

Set Cell_Reference = Range("A2:A68")

For i = 1 To Image_Names.Rows.Count
        Set Image = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Image_Location + "\" + Image_Names.Cells(i) + Image_Format)
        Image.Top = Cell_Reference.Cells(i).Top
        Image.Left = Cell_Reference.Cells(i).Left
        Image.ShapeRange.Height = 45
        Image.ShapeRange.Width = 90
Next i
End Sub
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Side note, but the inner loop is redundant. `Image_Names` only has one column.

Comment: use `DIR` to check if the image actually exists.

Comment: @BigBen: Thanks, I've removed the Integer. Often times- I also encounter the "Run-time error'1004': Unable to get the Insert property of the pictures class"

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your "Run-time error 1004"...I experienced similar when copying bigger amout of pictures from one sheet to another. Currently a solve it this way:

```
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Sheets(sName).Range(ColumnLetter & row + 1).PasteSpecial
    On Error GoTo -1
End If
```

Comment: sorry this didn't work for me :(. I threw back the same error code